# Some trouble with .htaccess and the removing of index.php

Tags: macos, .htaccess, yii, apache2, virtualhost

I am working on a project that uses composer and yii. I'll show you some information about the environment. I dont understand why .htaccess works on other machines but not in mine. I think the issue it's me =). I hope someone can help me.

- folders
- my virtualhost
- .htaccess file
- yii configuration
- some stuff
- logs

## Folders

The project has this folders:

```
~/Development/www/project/              - Project
~/Development/www/project/app           - Yii's index.php
~/Development/www/project/app/.htaccess - ...
...
...
```

## VirtualHost

Here my VirtualHost. I just put DocumentRoot, DirectoryIndex and ServerName. Is enough.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /Users/simonegentili/Development/Www/project/app
</VirtualHost>
```

## .htaccess

This is our .htaccess file (our because I work with other developers). This works on Linux environment of others team members. Dont work on my machine with MacOsX. I dont think the issue is due to MacOsX, but I think the issue is due to my bad configuration. Thus, ... here our .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

## Yii configuration

This is my configuration file.

```
return array(
    'components' => array(
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'caseSensitive' => false,
        ),
    ),
);
```

## The stuff ...

The problem is that if I keep showScriptName to true, all works file but I see URLs like "http:// project/index.php/site/index". When URL become "http:// project/site/index" I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /site/index was not found on this server.
```

## Logs

And finally, here my logs. I just get 404 error code. Why!?!?!?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2013:12:05:34 +0200] "GET /site/index HTTP/1.1" 404 208
[Thu Aug 22 12:05:34 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: ~/Development/Www/project/app/site, referer: http://project/index.php/site/index
```

PS. You see that the referer is "http:// project/index.php/site/index" 'couse first I open "http:// project/index.php/site/index" on my browser and second I change config file and refresh the page.

Can someone help me!?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing your URLManager rules change it to this:

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```